# Android app crashes upon start-up

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar

I am beginning to learn how to construct android apps. I was trying to add buttons to the action bar when the app began crashing. I will provide the MainActivity.java content as well as the logcat content.

```
logcat:
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1981)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:3187)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1797)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:115)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:32)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2578)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:224)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:232)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:147)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:199)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:285)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:507)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:934)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:292)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
07-04 13:31:15.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14357):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.test.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is *action_settings* created in res/menu/main_activity_actions.xml?

Comment: Where is getMenuInflater() defined?

Comment: Is it possible that the app is not able to find R.menu.main_activity_actions?

Comment: @ChitownDev It's defined in Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your menu function with:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return true;
}
```

I think the call to super was not needed and confusing things.